# jQuery sum add all TD values in table on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a form with few fields which does a small calculation. Once all the dropdowns are populated and clicked on **Add Button** It will display time for specific task. Likewise If you do the calculation couple of times the data will display in the table. and all values in time column will sum add together and display in another row. I have already implemented that. But it keeps adding to the existing value each time.

Refer to the image:

[image]

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atLab6sp/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calculate').click(function () {
        let tr = $("<tr/>").appendTo("#data tbody");
        $('#calc input, #calc select').each( function (index) {
            var input = $(this);
            $(tr).append('<td class=row-'+ $(input).attr("id") + '>' + $(input).val() + '</td>');
        });

        const componentFactor = $(tr).children(".row-component").text();
        const units = $(tr).children(".row-units").text();
        const total = componentFactor*units;

        $(tr).append('<td>' + total + '</td>');
        $("#calc")[0].reset();
        $("#total").html(sumColumn(5));
        function sumColumn(index) {
            var total = 0;
            $("td:nth-child(" + index + ")").each(function() {
                total += parseInt($(this).text(), 10) || 0;
            });  
            return total;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are including the total line in your sum function. The `.each` correctly hits every TD element at the right index, but it is also including the first line.

If you modify your sum function like so, it works.

```
function sumColumn(index) {
   var total = 0;
   $("td:nth-child(" + index + ")").each(function() {
       if(this.id !== 'total') {
          total += parseInt($(this).text(), 10) || 0;
       }                
    }); 
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same conclusion, you are adding total in your code; you can also use the following option:

```
function sumColumn(index) {
    var total = 0;

    $("tr> td:nth-child(" + index + ")").not(':first').each(function(i,item) {
       total += parseInt($(this).text(), 10) || 0;
    });  

    return total;
}
```

You can see it working here: <kbd>[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/atLab6sp/14/)</kbd>